# Can I specify a directory structure to be ignored with git submodule?

Tags: git

I have an external process running a recursive `git submodule update` command in my repository.

Some of my vendored dependencies are improperly setup and cause this to fail.

Is there any way I can add a file in the root directory of my dependencies so that this process will not search some or all of the nested directories?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `git submodule` combined with `foreach`. For instance:

```
git submodule foreach <script_to_get_not_vendor_folders> git submodule update
```

Comment: I cannot modify the external process to change it, so I am looking for a way to add a file to my directories.

Comment: Do you need to update this submodules??? If not, you can use 'git update-index --ignore-submodules'